# Unable to browse/view Java source files | VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I started using VS Code for Java programming. I have the required extension pack installed. Unlike Eclipse and IntelliJ I am not able to view source files of JDK packages, like java files in java.lang (String etc) or any other package.

Comment: Which extension are you using? I installed "Java Extension Pack" and then I was able to command+click on a class in the JDK to go to its definition.

Comment: Command + Click works, but I am asking is there a way to browse or directly search like you can do in Eclipse and IntelliJ

Comment: Maybe you could report it to the VScode github,it is a good suggestion